# How can I exit early from a chain of Promise.then in Promise.catch?

Tags: javascript, promise

I have this code ([view on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vtxhg9sz/1/)):

```
fetch('https://some.invalid.url').then(resp => resp.text())
.catch(err => console.log("got error: " + err))
.then(text => console.log("got text: " + text));
```

Currently this logs the two lines

```
"got error: TypeError: Failed to fetch"
"got text: undefined"
```

I would like it to only log the line

```
"got error: TypeError: Failed to fetch"
```

In other words, I would like the promise chain to end once the `.catch` is called and not go into the `.then`. How can I do this?

(I could throw an exception inside the `.catch`, but I think that results in a `unhandledrejection` event which is undesirable).

Comment: Why not put the `.catch()` in the end? Do you want to not handle exceptions from the `.then()` handler?

Comment: Yeah, I don't want my `.catch` to trigger if I throw an exception in the `.then`.

Comment: Then [use `.then(…, …)`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24662289/1048572) instead of `.then(…).catch(…)` or `.catch(…).then(…)`

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is that your `.catch()` returns a resolved promise (resolving with the return value of `console.log()`, ie `undefined`).

Either move the `.catch()` to the end of the promise chain

```js
fetch('https://some.invalid.url').then(resp => resp.text())
.then(text => console.log("got text: " + text))
.catch(err => console.log("got error: " + err));
```

or have it continue rejecting the chain (but note this will throw an uncaught promise rejection error)

```js
fetch('https://some.invalid.url').then(resp => resp.text())
.catch(err => {
  console.log("got error: " + err);
  return Promise.reject(err);
})
.then(text => console.log("got text: " + text));
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to swap the ordering so the `.catch()` is at the end of the chain.

```
fetch('https://some.invalid.url').then(resp => resp.text())
.then(text => console.log("got text should fail: " + text))
.catch(err => console.log("got error should fail: " + err));


fetch('https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js').then(resp => resp.text())
.then(text => console.log("got text that should succeed: " + text))
.catch(err => console.log("got error should succeed: " + err));
```

[(view on JSFiddle)](https://jsfiddle.net/kcm1803f/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Cancellable promises are not supported in ECMASCRIPT, but you could process catch clauses conditionally upon the type of error argument. E.G. Say you know every real error argument is non-null. Then you could

1. Throw `null` in a catch handler after logging or processing a real error.
2. Check if the `err` argument at the beginning of every catch handler to see if it is `null`. If so, re-throw the null error value immediately.
3. At the end of the promise chain, put an additional catch handler that re-throws its argument if it is **not** `null` - to report uncaught  errors during development.

Potentially this could be used to work around the absence of cancellable promises in JS  - but I do not suggest using it without  dire need. As comments have suggested, moving catch handlers to the end of the chain, or logging an error and re-throwing it in the same catch handler is the more common approach.